# Loading CSV file into Octave/MATLAB

Tags: matlab, csv, machine-learning, octave

**DATA**:

Assume the following data format (with a header line in the first row, 500+ rows):

Number, Number, Number, String, String, Number, Number, Number, String, Number, Number, Number

Example:
`1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,C85,S`

**MY CODE:**

Ignoring the columns 4, 9, 11 and 12(index starting from 1).

```
[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H] = textread("train.csv","%d %d %d %*q %s %d %d %d %*s %*s %f %*s %*s","delimiter",",","endofline","\n","headerlines","1");
```

**THE ERROR:**

```
error: invalid conversion from string to real scalar
error: fskipl: invalid number of lines specified
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.4/m/io/textread.m at line 71, column 5
```

I am new to octave and unable to understand the cause of the error. Please guide.

Comment: `...,"headerlines","1")` should probably be `...,"headerlines",1)`

Comment: That's right. Though the FORMAT is a little messed up. Using %q gives an error: `strread: A(I): index out of bounds; value 1 out of bound 0`

Answer (score 2):

Except for the issue with `headerlines` mentioned above, you have got 13 conversion specifications but only 12 columns, column 9 should correspond to one `%*s`, not two.
If I change the format string to

```
%d %d %d %*q %s %d %d %d %*s %f %*s %*s
```

parsing a small sample file works as expected in Matlab.